# Oracle SQL - How to show one to many relationship in a single row?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, string-concatenation

I have a table called MY_MOVIES with two columns: MOVIES and GENRES like this (the relationship is one movie to many genres):

```
GENRE         MOVIE
----------    --------------           
ACTION        MOVIE1
DRAMA         MOVIE1
CRIME         MOVIE2
DRAMA         MOVIE2
CRIME         MOVIE3
DRAMA         MOVIE3
ACTION        MOVIE4
ADVENTURE     MOVIE4
FANTASY       MOVIE4
ANIMATION     MOVIE5
ADVENTURE     MOVIE5
COMEDY        MOVIE5
```

This table have more than 100000 rows.

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
MOVIES        GENRES
----------    -------------- 
MOVIE1        ACTION, DRAMA
MOVIE2        CRIME, DRAMA
MOVIE3        CRIME, DRAMA
MOVIE4        ACTION, ADVENTURE, FANTASY
MOVIE5        ANIMATION, ADVENTURE, COMEDY
```

I was trying with PIVOT like this (having the idea of replace 0 and 1 to genres later):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_MOVIES 
PIVOT (COUNT(MOVIE) FOR GENRE in (SELECT DISTINCT(GENRE) FROM MY_MOVIES) as MOVIE_GENRES
```

I have been thinking I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using (presumably Oracle, given the PL/SQL tag).

Comment: Yes @GordonLinoff, i'm using Oracle. Sorry, I would tag it nex time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Oracle (version 11gR2 or later):

```
select movies,
       listagg(genre, ', ') within group (order by genre) as genres
from my_movies
group by movies;
```

Comment: thxs Gordon its perfect! :)

Comment: I'm getting ORA-01489 error (result of string concatenation is too long) sometimes, do you know what it can be? @gordon

Comment: @GordonShumway . . . There is a hard limit of 4,000 for `listagg()`.  Here is a blog that finds at least one way to address the issue:  https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/managing_overflows_in_listagg.